# If Else conditions in cakephp conditions parameter

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Can somebody help me that how to apply if else condition in conditions parameter while writing cakephp query. Please see example below:

```
 $customerList = $this->Asset->find("list", array(
            "conditions" => array(
                "AUser.status" => 1,
                'Asset.warranty_status_id' => $warranty_status_id
                ),
            "fields" => array("AUserProfile.user_id", "AUserProfile.company_name"),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'alias' => 'AUser',
                    'table' => 'users',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Asset.user_id = AUser.user_id',
                        'Asset.status = 1',
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'alias' => 'AUserProfile',
                    'table' => 'user_profiles',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'AUser.user_id = AUserProfile.user_id',
                    )
                )
            ),
            "order" => "AUserProfile.company_name ASC",
            "recursive" => $recursive
            )
        );
```

I need to write condition in conditions array block.

Comment: Can you provide the desired raw query you want. So that we can make the same query using cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you could use ternary operator like this:

```
// ...
'conditions' => CONDITION ? VALUE_FOR_TRUE : VALUE_FOR_FALSE;
// ...
```

Where CONDITION can be the same that you set inside if() statement.